# How to limit the number of links allowed for a React-Diagram node

Tags: reactjs

In my diagram, I have a rectangle node. one rectangle has top and bottom Port. I want to limit the links between nodes as follows.

**Expected:**
Just like a linked list, node top and bottom ports can have only one link each.
`node 1 -> bottom port` already connected to `node 2 -> top port` so no more links should not be allowed from the `node 1 -> bottom port`

```
+----------+
+  node 1  +
+----+-----+
     |
     |
+----+-----+
+  node 2  +
+----+-----+
     |
     |
+----+-----+
+  node 3  +
+----+-----+
```

**Following should not be allowed:**

```
+----------+
+  node 1  +
+----+-----+
     |
     +------------------+
     |                  |
+----+-----+       +----+-----+ 
+  node 2  +       +  node 3  +
+----+-----+       +----+-----+
```

I tried registering following listeners but none of them are fired when linking two nodes.

```
engine.getModel().getActiveNodeLayer().registerListener({
    entityRemoved: (event: any) => {
        console.log('node::entityRemoved', event);
    },
    eventDidFire: (event: any) => {
        console.log('node::eventDidFire', event);
    },
    eventWillFire: (event: any) => {
        console.log('node::eventWillFire', event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For googlers, I solved this by creating a custom port model:

```
class ConstrainedPortModel extends DefaultPortModel {
  
  constructor(options: ConstrainedPortModelOptions) {
    super(options);
    // save important options here
  }

  canLinkToPort(port: PortModel): boolean {
    if (/* Something not allowed */) {
      return false;
    }

    return super.canLinkToPort(port);
  }
}
```

And then adding my custom port in my Model's constructor:

```
class MyCustomNodeModel extends NodeModel {

  constructor(options: MyCustomNodeModelOptions) {
    super({
      ...options,
    });

    this.addPort(new ConstrainedPortModel({
        in: true,
        // Other important constraint options here
    }));
  }
```